# looking for duplicate entries using core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I am looking for duplicated usernames in a login/sign up form using core data. Here is my code:

```
let context = managedObjectContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyEntityName", in: managedObjectContext)
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
request.entity = entity

var Fetcherror: Error?
var mutableFetchResults = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
// if mutableFetchResults == nil {
// print ("error")
// }

if mutableFetchResults?.contains(where: usernamefield.text){
    print("duplicates")
    return
} else {
// add the user
}
```

However,I am getting the following error in the first if statement:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool'

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your `MyEntityName` class in your question, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mutableFetchResults` results array does not contain `String` but `User` type. And `usernamefield.text` is of type `String`. That  is why you cannot use `contains` the way you use it.
Try to map your `mutableFetchResults` to an array of type `String` first.

```
if let mutableFetchResults = mutableFetchResults {
     let stringArray = mutableFetchResults.flatMap { $0.username }
     if stringArray.contains(where: usernamefield.text) {
         print("duplicates")
         return
     }
}
```

`username` is the `String` property on your `User` class you want to check.

Your complete code should look something like this.

```
let context = managedObjectContext
let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()

var fetchError: Error?
var mutableFetchResults = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
// if mutableFetchResults == nil {
// print ("error")
// }

if let mutableFetchResults = mutableFetchResults {
   let stringArray = mutableFetchResults.flatMap { $0.username }
   if stringArray.contains(where: usernamefield.text) {
      print("duplicates")
      return
} else {
// add the user
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but what is someStringProperty?

Comment: @dreamcode I adjusted my answer to explain `someStringProperty`

Comment: gives another error :Value of type 'Any' has no member 'username' ,which is the property I want to check

Comment: @dreamcode please try my update code and add your `User` class code to your question not to my answer.

Comment: There are persisting errors:     Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '(String?) throws -> Bool'

Comment: @dreamcode adjusted code to user `flatMap` instead of `map` to filter out nil. Please try updated code.

Comment: The error disappeared after I removed Where and unwrapped the string.Thank you!

Comment: @dreamcode you could have also just used `flatMap` instead of `map` as in my updated code. `flatMap` will filter out nil.